# Trigger that insert into a dblink table

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle10g

I am trying to do a trigger, that select values into some tables, and then insert them into another table.

So, for now I got this. There is a lot of columns, so I don't copy them, it is only varchar2 values, and this part works, so I don't think it is useful :

```
   create or replace 
TRIGGER TRIGGER_FICHE 
AFTER INSERT ON T_AG 

BEGIN
  declare 
  begin


INSERT INTO t_ag_hab@DBLINK_DEV
()
values
();

/*commit;*/
end;
END;
```

Stored procedure where trigger will be called(again a lot of parameters, not relevant to copy them :

```
INSERT INTO T_AG()
       VALUES
                  ();


commit work;
```

The thing is, we cannot do commit into a trigger, I read that, and understand it.

But, how can I see an update of my table, with the new value?

When the process is runnign, there is nor error, but I don't see the new line into t_ag_hab.

I know it's not very clear, but I don't know how to explain it other way.
How can I fix this?,

Comment: I miss telling the important part : oracle 10g. Add the tag.

Comment: The following guide is for PostgreSQL database which uses PL/pgSQL syntax for database queries and etc. PL/pgSQL is very similar to Oracle's PL/SQL syntax; so you might find that link useful: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: You won't see the entry in the remote table (or any table) from another session until the transaction is committed, but you should be able to see it from within the same transaction. Are you say that you want the remote table's insert to be visible elsewhere before the commit - which would make it persist even the transaction is then rolled back? Except for some logging cases, that would be an odd requirement.

Comment: No that is not the problem. The thing is, when the trigger is finished, I don't see the new line in the table. Too put it clearly, I m doing the insert in a stored procedure, and after the insert (so after the trigger), I am doing a `commit work`, but nothing. In fact, I must, at the  `commit work` , I must do more like a commit on the dblink.

Comment: Your `commit work` will commit the data in both the local and remote tables. If your local data is visible after your transaction ends but the remote data is not then something else is happening - something is deleting it, or you're looking at a pre-insert version of the remote data in another transaction (does it ever appear?). Or your link isn't inserting to the remote database you think it is; are you querying `t_ag_ab@dblink_dev` or querying from within the other DB, and have you checked the DB link definition and - if relevant - the `tnsnames.ora` being used?

Comment: Indeed, the name of the DBLINK confuses me, and it was a totally different DB where I was connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're inserting into a remove table via a database link, you have [a distributed transaction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/server.1111/e25789/transact.htm#CHDJCBCF):

> ... distributed transaction processing is more complicated because the database must coordinate the committing or rolling back of the changes in a transaction as an atomic unit. The entire transaction must commit or roll back.

When you commit, you're committing both the local insert and the remote insert performed by your trigger, as an atomic unit. You cannot commit one without the other, and you don't have to do anything extra to commit the remote change:

> The two-phase commit mechanism is transparent to users who issue distributed transactions. In fact, users need not even know the transaction is distributed. A COMMIT statement denoting the end of a transaction automatically triggers the two-phase commit mechanism. No coding or complex statement syntax is required to include distributed transactions within the body of a database application.

If you can't see the inserted data from the remote database afterwards then something else has deleted it after the commit, or more likely you're looking at the wrong database.

One slight downside (though also a feature) of a database link is that it hides the details of where the work is being done. You can drop and recreate a link to make your code update a different target database without having to modify the code itself. But that means your code doesn't know where the insert is actually going - you'd need to check the data dictionary to see where the link is pointing. And even then you might not know as the link can be using a TNS alias to identify the database, and changes to the `tnsnames.ora` aren't visible from within the database.

If you can see the data after committing by querying `t_ag_ab@dblink_dev` from the same database you ran your procedure, but you can't see if when queried locally from the database you expect that to be pointing to, then the link isn't pointing where you think it is. The insert is going to one database, and you are performing your query against a different one. Only you can decide which is the 'correct' database though; and either redefine the link (or TNS entry, if appropriate), or change where you're doing the query.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. As told in the question comment, in fact, the name of the DBLINK, that was already created, wronged me on the DB. I was inserting in an old DB, while the DBLINK hasn't been changed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand you requirement clearly. For updating records in main table and insert the old records in audit table. we can use the below query as a trigger.(MS-SQL)

```
Create trigger trg_update ON T_AGENT
AFTER UPDATE AS 
BEGIN

UPDATE Tab1
SET COL1 = I.COL1, COL2=I.COL2
FROM INSERTED I INNER JOIN Tab1 ON I.COL3=Tab1.Col3

INSERT Tab1_Audit(COL1,COL2,COL3)
SELECT Tab1 FROM DELETED

RETURN;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

So far what you presented is just for `Inserting` trigger. If you want to see the update action done try to add `Update` like this example.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER validate_update
  2  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON T_AGENT
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    IF UPDATING('ACCOUNT_ID') THEN     -- do something like this when updating
  6      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ERROR');  -- add your action here
  7    ELSIF INSERTING THEN
  8      INSERT INTO t_ag_hab@DBLINK_DEV() values();
  9    END IF;
  10  END;
  11  /

  Trigger created.
```